# получение информации о windows с помощью c++

Tags: c++, windows

мне нужно получить информацию о системе windows с помощью стандартной библиотеки c++. я нашел информацию только об устаревших функциях, которые на данный момент уже не работают.
есть ли возможность точно определить версию windows, ее разрядность и версию сборки?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

можно, через реестр. Ветка HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

Comment: т.е теперь минусуют если не написал за кого то код? Если глянуть эту ветку, то можно увидеть ВСЮ информацию.

Comment: Можно и просто переменные среды посмотреть с тем же успехом.

Comment: в переменных среды нет всего. А вот то что нарисовали выше, это как раз тяжелые финтифлюшки для обращения к этой ветке

Comment: я не минусую, спасибо за подсказку :)

Answer (score 1):

я через wmid классы запрашивал информацию о системе, о версии, драйверах итдитп. все есть в документации у мелкомягких, легко гуглится, какие есть параметры, которые нужно запрашивать

тут используются qt классы, но можно и без. Этот код оттестирован и рабочий

```
static int getOsInfo(IWbemServices* services, QStringList* result_info)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    const int OK = 0, FAIL = -1;

    IEnumWbemClassObject* enumerator = getEnumerator(services, _bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"));
    if (nullptr == enumerator)
        return FAIL;

    IWbemClassObject* obj = nullptr;
    ULONG ret_objs_num = 0; // Количество полученных объектов на запрос.

    HRESULT hr = enumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &obj, &ret_objs_num);
    if (WBEM_S_NO_ERROR != hr || 0 == ret_objs_num || nullptr == obj)
    {
        enumerator->Release();
        return FAIL;
    }

    QStringList info;
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"Version");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"Caption");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"CountryCode");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"CurrentTimeZone");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"InstallDate");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"LastBootUpTime");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"Locale");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"OSLanguage");
    getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"SerialNumber");

    if (info.isEmpty())
    {
        obj->Release();
        enumerator->Release();
        return FAIL;
    }

    auto it  = info.begin();
    auto end = info.end();
    for ( ; it != end; ++it)
        (*it).prepend("OS: ");

    result_info->append(info);

    obj->Release();
    enumerator->Release();
    return OK;
}
```

я вот так пользуюсь

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static int getSystemShortInfoWin2(QStringList& sys_info)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    const int OK = 0, FAIL = -1;
    int ret = OK;

    HRESULT hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "I can't to initialize COM library. Error: " << hres;
        exit(-2);
        return FAIL;
    }

    IWbemLocator* locator = nullptr;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WbemLocator
            , 0
            , CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER
            , IID_IWbemLocator
            , (LPVOID*)&locator
            );
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "I can't to create locator. Error: " << hres;
        CoUninitialize();
        return FAIL;
    }

    IWbemServices* services = nullptr;
    hres = locator->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t("ROOT\\CIMV2")
            , NULL
            , NULL
            , NULL
            , 0L
            , NULL
            , nullptr
            , &services
            );
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "I can't to connect to WMI server. Error: " << hres;
        locator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        exit(-2);
        return FAIL;
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            services
            , RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT
            , RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE
            , NULL
            , RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL
            , RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE
            , NULL
            , EOAC_NONE
            );
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "I can't to set proxy blanket. Error: " << hres;
        services->Release();
        locator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FAIL;
    }

    // ...

    QStringList os_info;
    result = getOsInfo(services, &os_info);

    services->Release();
    locator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    // ...
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static IEnumWbemClassObject* getEnumerator(IWbemServices* services, BSTR query)
{
    IEnumWbemClassObject* p = nullptr;

    HRESULT hres = services->ExecQuery(
            _bstr_t("WQL")
            , query
            , WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY// | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY
            , NULL
            , &p
            );
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "I can't to query. Error: " << hres;
        return nullptr;
    }

    return p;
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void getEnumeratorItem(
        IWbemClassObject* obj
        , QStringList* result_info
        , LPCWSTR item_name
        )
{
    if (nullptr == obj)
        return;

    _variant_t v;

    HRESULT hr = obj->Get(item_name, 0, &v, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;

    QString info = QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)item_name) + " = ";

    switch(v.vt)
    {
        case VT_BSTR:
            info.append(QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)(_bstr_t(v).GetBSTR())));
            break;
        case VT_I2:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<qint16>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_UI2:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<quint16>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_INT:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<int>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_UINT:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<unsigned int>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_I4:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<qint32>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_UI4:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<quint32>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_I8:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<qint64>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_UI8:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<quint64>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_R4:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<float>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_R8:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<double>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_DATE:
        {
            QString date_time;
            getDateTimeFromWMI(static_cast<double>(v), date_time);
            info.append(date_time);
            break;
        }
        case VT_BOOL:
            info.append(QString::number(static_cast<bool>(v)));
            break;
        case VT_EMPTY:
        case VT_NULL:
            info.append("(empty)");
            break;
        default:
            info.append("(Unsupported by DiViLab)");
    }

    result_info->append(info);
}
```